# SQL JOIN statements with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

The Problem:

Construct the SQL statement to find the number of attendees for every meeting. Display the following columns:

- Count of meeting attendees
- Meeting ID
- Meeting start date and time
- Meeting end date and time

There are 5 tables in this database(person, building, room, meeting, person_meeting

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| person_id | first_name | last_name  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         1 | Tom        | Hanks      |
|         2 | Anne       | Hathaway   |
|         3 | Tom        | Cruise     |
|         4 | Meryl      | Streep     |
|         5 | Chris      | Pratt      |
|         6 | Halle      | Berry      |
|         7 | Robert     | De Niro    |
|         8 | Julia      | Roberts    |
|         9 | Denzel     | Washington |
|        10 | Melissa    | McCarthy   |
+-----------+------------+------------+

+-------------+----------------------+
| building_id | building_name        |
+-------------+----------------------+
|           1 | Headquarters         |
|           2 | Main Street Buidling |
+-------------+----------------------+

+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| room_id | room_number | building_id | capacity |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|       1 | 100         |           1 |        5 |
|       2 | 200         |           1 |        4 |
|       3 | 300         |           1 |       10 |
|       4 | 10          |           2 |        4 |
|       5 | 20          |           2 |        4 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+

+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| meeting_id | room_id | meeting_start       | meeting_end         |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |       1 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          2 |       1 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          3 |       1 | 2016-12-25 11:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          4 |       2 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          5 |       4 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          6 |       5 | 2016-12-25 14:00:00 | 2016-12-25 16:00:00 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+

+-----------+------------+
| person_id | meeting_id |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |
|        10 |          1 |
|         1 |          2 |
|         2 |          2 |
|         3 |          2 |
|         4 |          2 |
|         5 |          2 |
|         6 |          2 |
|         7 |          2 |
|         8 |          2 |
|         9 |          3 |
|        10 |          3 |
|         1 |          4 |
|         2 |          4 |
|         8 |          5 |
|         9 |          5 |
|         1 |          6 |
|         2 |          6 |
|         3 |          6 |
+-----------+------------+
```

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT Count(person_id) AS “Count of meeting attendees” ,meeting_id,meeting_start,meeting_end    
FROM meeting M ,person_meeting PM    
WHERE M. meeting_id=PM. meeting_id    
Group by PM.meeting_id,M.meeting_start,M.meeting_end;
```

The error I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'of meeting attendees” ,meeting_id,meeting_start,meet
ing_end



FROM meeting M ' at line 1
```

Please Help me, I am not sure What I am doing wrong. I have not been able to find a solution for this problem

Comment: you could start by using ANSI joins....

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Don't give you columns aliases that need to be escaped.  So, use underscores rather than spaces.  This fixes your problem with the weird double quote characters:

```
SELECT COUNT(pm.person_id) AS num_attendees,
       m.meeting_id, m.meeting_start, m.meeting_end    
FROM meeting m JOIN
     person_meeting PM    
     ON m.meeting_id = pm.meeting_id    
GROUP BY m.meeting_id, m.meeting_start, m.meeting_end ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error text I would try changing the name of your COUNT() column to just 'Count', since the error message starts just after the first space in your column name

EDIT:

I will also second Gordon Linoff's statement: 
never do this:

```
FROM tbla a, tblb b
WHERE a.columna = b.columnb
```

That's a regular old join, and it should be written as such:

```
FROM tbla A
JOIN tblb B ON a.columna = b.columnb
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that can be changed. First meeting_id column belongs to both table so you have to define which table's column. And then the column naming must have error depending on error description you have provided.

```
SELECT Count(person_id) AS "Count" ,M.meeting_id,meeting_start,meeting_end    
FROM meeting M 
INNER JOIN person_meeting PM ON M.meeting_id=PM.meeting_id
Group by M.meeting_id,M.meeting_start,M.meeting_end;
```